# JavaScript - How can I get the last different index in string but

Tags: javascript, string, split

Hi I'm going to make a calculator and I want a +/- button. I want to get the latest `*`, `-`, `+`, `/` in the string and define whats the laststring.

For example:

```
str="2+3*13"
```

I want this to be split into:

```
strA="2+3*"

strB="13"
```

Another example:

```
str="3-2+8"
```

Should split into:

```
strA="3-2+"

strB="8"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) and one of the [substring methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype#Methods):

```
var strA, strB,
    // a generic solution for more operators might be useful
    index = Math.max(str.lastIndexOf("+"), str.lastIndexOf("-"), str.lastIndexOf("*"), str.lastIndexOf("/"));
if (index < 0) {
    strA = "";
    strB = str;
} else {
    strA = str.substr(0, index+1);
    strB = str.substr(index+1);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... This one's GREAT, I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp), [match](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp), and Regular Expressions:

```
str="3-2+8"
strA = str.replace(/\d+$/, "")
strB = str.match(/\d+$/)[0]

console.log(str, strA, strB);
> 3-2+8 3-2+ 8
```

Comment: @user210000: `replace` does not modify the `str`, so why not?

Comment: As @Bergi said: the original `str` variable is not modified in any way during this entire operation (as evident by the console.log at the end of the code block). The `.replace()` function is used specifically for the purpose of setting `strA` to the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression and split method:

```
var parts = "2 + 4 + 12".split(/\b(?=\d+\s*$)/);
```

Will give you and array:

```
["2 + 4 + ", "12"]
```

Couple of tests:

```
"(2+4)*230" -> ["(2+4)*", "230"]
"(1232-74) / 123 " -> ["(1232-74) / ", "123 "]
"12 * 32" -> ["12 * ", "32"]
```